# determining web http authentication methods

Tags: http-authentication

How do you determine if a REST webservice is using Basic, Kerberos, NTLM, or one of the many other authentication methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you send an unauthenticated request the service has to respond with a "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" and the response contains a `WWW-Authenticate` header that specifies what authentication scheme is expected (`Basic`, `Digest`), the security realm and any other specific value (like Digets's nonce). So if the server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="example.com",
                        qop="auth,auth-int",
                        nonce="...",
                        opaque="..."
```

it wants a Digest authentication. If the response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="example.com"
```

then it wants a Basic authentication. Some (poorly) implemented servers/sites don't handle the Basic correctly and respond directly with 403 Forbidden instead of challenging first.

NTLM is similar in as the server reponds with a 401 and a WWW-Authenticate header with the value `NTLM`, but there is no official public spec for it, since is Microsoft proprietary. There are various [reverse](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html) [engineered](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/ntlm.html) descriptions.

Unfortunately REST does not come with a WSDL style description of service to discover the authentication scheme used *a priori*.

Comment: the issue was that the REST service was not returning with any WWW-Authenticate header at all in the 401 so I had to manually specify the header

Comment: I only need 1 penny for every web site that does that (not handle Basic with correct challenge) and I can retire...

Answer (score 4):

You send it a request, presumably get an HTTP 401 code, and look at the `WWW-Authenticate` header that (per [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)) the response `MUST` include.  If instead you get a 403 or some other weird status, or a missing `WWW-Authenticate` header, you curse at website authors that don't follow the core HTTP RFC, and start sniffing the traffic to try to reverse engineer what nonstandard mess they've done *this* time;-).

Comment: I wish I could select two valid answers, the issue was that the REST service was not returning a WWW-Authenticate header so I had to manually add the header with code from:
http://devproj20.blogspot.com/2008/02/assigning-basic-authorization-http.html

Comment: @Seph, yeah, the number of broken sites around the web is staggering, isn't it?  No matter how clear an RFC is (and it doesn't get much clearer than `MUST`;-) there's _always_ plenty of "programmers" (HA!) who think they're just too special to have to read, or abide by, boring docs...:-(

Answer (score 1):

If it's a black box scenario, I usually connect with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), and inspect the actual traffic.