# Android: Access a secure xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, http-post, http-get

I used a xml parser many times but the only thing now is the server where the xml file is stored asks for a username and password (i have them) but how do i login with a httpGet or httpPost.

Thanks in advance.

(PS: The username and password are always the same)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to know how to do HTTP Authentication in android.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android). There you will learn how to do HTTP authentication in android.

EDIT: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463723/determining-web-http-authentication-methods) to see how to determine authetication type needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But i tried it and it doesn't work. Maybe you can see what type of authencation is needed for this url: http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-avt?station=Utrecht

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.net.URLConnection` is described very well in the following link by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Following that thread you can easily send httpGet or httpPost and login to server.

Comment: Maybe this sounds stupid but i can't find it on the given link :P

Comment: this thread is about working with httpGet or httpPost. not exactly fits with your requirement for authentication but helps you to know how to work with httpGet or httpPost.